# Collections.sort() issue in java7

Tags: sorting, collections, java-7

Is there a sort issue with java7? I am using Collections.sort(list, comparator)

When I switched over to java7, I noticed that the sorting resulted in a different list compared to the result when I was using java6.

Example: List = [d, e, b, a, c, f, g, h]

In java6 Collections.sort(List, comparator) resulted in [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]

In java7 Collections.sort(List, comparator) resulted in [b, a, c, d, e, f, g, h]

The first two values in the list have been swapped.

Comment: Report a bug to oracle..

Comment: Seems unlikely that Collections.sort is broken.  What is the actual data with which you've observed this result (an array of chars or strings as shown)?  And are you passing a Comparator to it?

Comment: If you could show an example code that have this result it's better to see what could be the problem

Comment: Show the code of your comparator

Answer (score 9):

Java 7 switched from [Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) to [Tim sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). It might result in slight changes in order with "*broken comparators*" (quoting comment in source code of [`Arrays` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)):

```
/**
 * Old merge sort implementation can be selected (for
 * compatibility with broken comparators) using a system property.
 * Cannot be a static boolean in the enclosing class due to
 * circular dependencies. To be removed in a future release.
 */
```

Try running your JVM with:

```
java -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
```

It's not clear what "*broken comparator*" means, but apparently it can result in different order of elements in sorted arrays.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note, that might be causing confusion.  Collections.sort is a stable sort.  This means for equal elements, it maintains their original ordering, so:

if a == b, then

```
Collections.sort([d, e, b, a, c, f, g, h]) = [b, a, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

and

```
Collections.sort([d, e, a, b, c, f, g, h]) = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

Seems likely to me that either that is what your seeing, or the Comparator in question (or the objects being sorteds' natural ordering) isn't working the way you expect it to.